# How to explain the difference in significance level and type I error in permutation test of Pearson correlation on non-normal bivariate data

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, pearson-r, permutation-test, type-i-and-ii-errors

Let $x,y$ be sampled from a bivariate distribution $\mathcal{D}$ with zero covariance / no correlation.

Let $r(x,y)$ be the Pearson correlation between $x$ and $y$. Let $H_0$ be that there is no association between $x$ and $y$ and let $H_1$ be that there is. I calculate the p-value using a permutation test as follows: Let $\hat{y}$ be a randomly permuted copy of $y$ and calculate $r(x,\hat{y})$. Repeat the permutation and calculation of Pearson correlation $m\gg n$ times. Let $r_i$ be the Pearson correlation between $x$ and the $i$-th permutation of $y$. Then the p-value for this test is:

$$p = \frac{|\{i : |r_i| > |r(x,y)| \}|}{m}$$

That is, the estimated p-value is the proportion of the absolute correlations between $x$ and permuted versions of $y$ that are greater than the absolute correlation between the original $x$ and $y$.

I want to calculate the type I error. I repeat all of the above $l$ (many) times, each time calculating a p-value for a new $x,y$ sampled from the same bivariate distribution $\mathcal{D}$ (with zero correlation). Let $p_i$ be the p-value for the permutation test on the $i$-th sample. Given that every pair $x,y$ was sampled from a bivariate distribution with zero correlation, we expect the type I error to be approximately equal to the significance level. Lets choose a significance level of $0.05$. Then I believe I should find that:

$$\text{Type I error} = \frac{|\{ i = [1,l]:p_i \leq 0.05 \}|}{l} \approx 0.05$$

And indeed I find this to be true when I sample from a bivariate normal distribution with zero correlation. That is, at a 0.05 significance level, I find that in about 0.05 of the tests I reject $H_0$. So the type I error is approximately equal to whatever significance level I choose.

But when I sample from a bivariate t-distribution with fat tails (say degree of freedom of 3), I get a type I error of about 0.25 at a 0.05 significance level.

(I know a t-distribution goes against the normality assumption of Pearson. But that's the goal of my experiment - to see what the consequences are)

My question is this:

I'm having some difficulty describing the difference between the significance level and type I error in this case. Is it correct to conclude here that when using Pearson on bivariate t-distributed data with fat tails, the probability of incorrectly rejecting $H_0$ using a permutation test is higher than the significance level, and therefore, non-existing associations are incorrectly identified as significant more than expected?

Is there something else that could be causing the difference between type I error and significance level? And does my methodology seem sound?